# Was the "Two Spirit" played by a real berdache?

Tags: actors, special-effects, lovecraft-country

In *Lovecraft Country* S1E04, "A History of Violence", Tic, Leti, and Montrose, following the trail of Titus Braithwaite's last voyage in the secret vault, encounter a "corpse" that revives to reveal a *berdache*, a "two spirit", with both male and female features (visible because the corpse is nude).

Was this character played by an actual intersex actor, was a makeup effect used, or was this effect done in CGI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the website lezwatch.tv Monique Candelaria is a cisgender woman.
https://lezwatchtv.com/actor/monique-candelaria/

It is not clear if they used cgi or a prosthetic but there is a behind the scenes photo of her getting a cast made of her pelvic area.

https://redcarpetreporttv.com/2020/09/06/talking-to-lovecraft-countys-monique-candelaria-about-yahima-in-ep4-bts-trailer-interview-hbo-arawak-dialogue-lovecraftcountry/